# Problem with VHD mounting: "a single mountpoint must be specified"

Tags: mount, hard-drive, virtualization

I have followed [this whole article] on how to mount VHD in Linux with vdfuse](http://rrbits.com/epb/2014/09/14/mount-a-vhd-or-vdi-in-linux-with-vdfuse) and everything went great except the last step. When I type `vdfuse -r "/media/mike/DATA/VM-VHD/SGOS.vhd" ~/Test` (I just want to copy one file from that VHD), in return I get this:

```
ERROR: a single mountpoint must be specified

DESCRIPTION: This Fuse module uses the VirtualBox access library to open a 
VirtualBox supported VD image file and mount it as a Fuse file system.  The
mount point contains a flat directory containing the files EntireDisk,
Partition1 .. PartitionN.  These can then be loop mounted to access the
underlying file systems
Version: 0.83

USAGE: vdfuse [options] -f image-file mountpoint
    -h  help
    -r  readonly
    -t  specify type (VDI, VMDK, VHD, or raw; default: auto)
    -f  VDimage file
    -s  Snapshot file(s) to load on top of the image file
    -a  allow all users to read disk
    -w  allow all users to read and write to disk
    -g  run in foreground
    -v  verbose
    -d  debug

NOTE: you must add the line "user_allow_other" (without quotes)
to /etc/fuse.confand set proper permissions on /etc/fuse.conf
for this to work.
```

I'm sure I have `user_allow_other` in configuration file and permissions are set properly. What should that "mountpoint" be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `-f` option. It also looks like `vdfuse` needs to be told what the `type` of file it is.  The command should be:

```
vdfuse -r -t VHD -f "/media/mike/DATA/VM-VHD/SGOS.vhd" ~/Test
```

The `-f` specifies the file that you're mounting. The `-t` means what type, since you're using VHD, that is what is specified.

Also make sure that you uncomment the line for "user_allow_other" in `/etc/fuse.conf`.  To uncomment just paste the line below to a terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/#user_allow_other/user_allow_other/' /etc/fuse.conf
```

the `#` is used to comment a line in a file and the `sed` line above removes the `#` from that line.

In my example below I am showing step-by-step of how I am able to access the files contained within my VM:

```
terrance@terrance-Linux:~$ vdfuse -r -t VDI -f "/home/terrance/VirtualBox VMs/Kubuntu 16.04/Kubuntu 16.04.vdi" ~/Test
terrance@terrance-Linux:~$ cd Test
terrance@terrance-Linux:~/Test$ ls -al
total 41939973
dr-xr-x---  1 terrance terrance          0 Jun  9 14:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 61 terrance terrance        4096 Jun 10 16:11 ..
-r--------  1 terrance terrance 21474836480 Jun  9 14:10 EntireDisk
-r--------  1 terrance terrance 17178820608 Jun  9 14:10 Partition1
-r--------  1 terrance terrance  4292870144 Jun  9 14:10 Partition5
terrance@terrance-Linux:~/Test$ sudo mount -o loop Partition1 /mnt
terrance@terrance-Linux:~/Test$ ls /mnt
bin   dev  home        lib    lost+found  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  initrd.img  lib64  media       opt  root  sbin  sys  usr  vmlinuz
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I type `vdfuse -r -f "/media/mike/DATA/VM-VHD/SGOS.vhd" ~/Test`, I get `ERROR: cannot autodetect disk type of /media/mike/DATA/VM-VHD/SGOS.vhd`. What I'm doing wrong now? By the way, what is uncommenting?

Comment: @PKM Modified my answer with a little more explanation for you.  :)

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting `ERROR: Invalid EBR signature found on image`, can be VHD corupted? /EDIT: the OS on VHD has FDE, could that cause this problem?

Comment: @PKM What version of VirtualBox are you running?  Looks like it is a bug in some older versions https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox-ose/+bug/759988

Comment: I use 5.0.20, according to VirtualBox website it's the actual version

Comment: @PKM Sorry, I missed the part of FDE.  Is that in the VM or on your actual OS?  If in the VM, I could see how that might happen because it can't access the drive since it should ask for your password at startup of the VM to decrypt the drive just for the time being.

Comment: It is VM, and I did some bad updates there and now it's unable to boot, that's why I wanted to access its VHD and backup important file. I think the only solution to this then will be creating new VM and VHD, do a fresh install on it, and then attach VHD with "broken" VM to it as a second drive and try to access it. Right now I tried mounting non-FDE VHD from other VM and it works, so problem is in FDE and your answer is right. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @PKM No problem!  I am very glad that you found another solution to help you in getting your files out of the VHD.  =)